# how to use cv.polylines in opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv

```
cv.polylines(mat, new cv.MatVector(), false, [255, 0, 0, 255], 5);
```

no error using this but it doesn't draw anything since I don't know how to connect points to MatVector, how could I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

```
const strokeWidth = 4;
const markersVector = new cv.MatVector();
const mv = new cv.Mat(markers.length, 1, cv.CV_32SC2);
[{x: 10, y: 10}, ...].forEach(({ x, y }, idx) => {
  mv.intPtr(idx, 0)[0] = x;
  mv.intPtr(idx, 0)[1] = y;
});

markersVector.push_back(mv);

cv.polylines(mat, markersVector, false, new cv.Scalar(255,0,0), strokeWidth);
```